# Arranging numbers within the digits in descending order without using arrays

Tags: java

I want to arrange the digits of a number in descending order without using arrays. When I am using String it gives run time error. 
For example:

```
Input: 2436
Output: 6432
```

Here is what I wrote but the problem is the first digit isn't getting printed which is not the expected output.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num,n,r=0,FinalNo=0;
    System.out.println("Enter any number");
    num=sc.nextInt();
    n=num;
    while(n>0) {
        r=n%10;
        n=n/10;
        FinalNo=(FinalNo*10)+r;
    }
    System.out.println("The number in descending order is "+FinalNo);
}
```

Comment: Although the false one, it gives an output.

Comment: Did you hit _Enter_ after you have entered a number ?

Comment: Create a string from the int (or read it from the console as a string), split the string at the empty string, then sort it.

Comment: You are not using any arrays, despite what the title says

Comment: @GeorgeCernat what do you mean? The title says "without using arrays".

Comment: @AkshitKumar my bad, I read that wrong

Comment: Why dont you want to use array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your number is not greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you can use Redix Sort algorithm. It works fine with the complexity of `O(n)`. Here, you can find the solution in following code, that doesn't use any array or lists and Strings.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 45322;
        int sortedNumber = 0;

    /*
     * This loop checks for each digit starting from 9 to 0. 
     * In case of ascending order it should be 0 to 9.
     */
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        int tmpNumber = number;
        while (tmpNumber > 0) {
            int digit = tmpNumber % 10;
            // Check for the greatest digit in the given number
            if (digit == i) {
                sortedNumber *= 10;
                sortedNumber += digit;
            }
            tmpNumber /= 10;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sortedNumber); // prints 54322.
}
```

I think that should work for you.

Comment: Why did you put value of i as 9 i the for loop?

Comment: For the digits in the range [0-9]. It checks for the largest one i.e. 9 first and then stores it (if found in given number!) and so on. I have edited the code with comments, to make it more understandable.

Comment: K Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

Your example reverses the inputted value, but does not sort it in descending order. You're not allowed to use Strings or arrays (school assignment?), but how about lists?

```
List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<>(); // Because ArrayList uses an array internally
while (n > 0) {
    ints.add(n % 10);
    n = n / 10;
}
ints.sort((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b, a)); // Sort in reverse order
System.out.print("The digits in reversed order are: ");
ints.forEach(System.out::print);
System.out.println();
```

Comment: I don't want to use list and any other type of shortcut type of thing i want to know about the classic method to solve this.

Comment: I've never had to solve this problem so I don't know the classic solution. However, there was a link posted in comment to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971256/how-to-sort-integer-digits-in-ascending-order-without-strings-or-arrays

You should be able to adapt the answer given there.